# can a webservice take a callback function as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a .NET webservice which has to perform several actions and I would like to display progress via a callback to a javascript function.

this is the function

'//vb.NET

```
  <WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
       <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, XMLSerializeString:=False)> _
       Public Shared Function RebuildLuceneIndex(options As List(Of RebuildLuceneOption), callbackProgress As Action(Of String, Boolean))

        For Each opt As RebuildLuceneOption In options
            Try
                Select Case opt.Action.ToLower()
                    Case "clear"
                  .......
                End Select
                callbackProgress.Invoke(opt.Action.ToLower(), True)
            Catch ex As Exception
                callbackProgress.Invoke(opt.Action.ToLower(), False)
            End Try
        Next

    End Function
```

Im struggling to workout the jQuery syntax for calling this webservice passing a json array of strings, and a callback  to the function which i can then callback into to show progress.

//javascript

```
function RebuildLuceneProgressCallback(InvokedMethod, Successfull) {
    if (Successfull) {
        console.log(InvokedMethod + ' Succeeded');
    }
    else {
        console.log(InvokedMethod + ' Failed');
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split your method up into two methods: Begin & End. See this article on [Server-Side Asynchronous Web Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480516.aspx).

Then in your jQuery call, you need to call the Begin() method, followed by subsequent requests to check if the method has finished.